# Angular synchronize objects between components

Tags: angular, typescript, observer-pattern

I am creating an Angular 4 app and I am having some problems with my data concept.

I have an app with 3 components. Each of this components has some settings like name, date, List... which are different for each component. Now I am trying to implement the ability to synchronize this settings between the components.
For example I want to enable that the component 1 synchronizes the date with component 2. So if I change the date on component 2 it also should change on component 1. I want to enable/disable this in my app. So if I don´t want to synchronize I disable it and each component has it own settings again. And it should be possible to synchronize with different components. So component 1 synchronizes date with component 2. And component 1 synchronizes List with component 3.

I already have implemented something simliar in Java with the Guava EventBus and I think that this might be possible to do with Observer but I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great case of using [**Shared services**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or [**Ngrx**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx).

The data is maintained throught the application using these two ways. My suggestion is to go for Ngrx if you app size is huge and huge shared services for small to medium apps.

Comment: I am already using shared services for some other things and I already thought that it could be possible to do that with shared services. But what is the best way to use it in this case? Should I store the settings (name, date...) in the shared service?

Comment: Yes that is the way to go have a model in shred service